# Opendaylight: How to add a NORMAL action in Openflow?

Tags: openflow, opendaylight, openvswitch

I'm new to opendaylight and Openflow and have a few questions.

I'm using Open vSwitch as the vSwitch.

Normally, in the Open vSwitch , the default flow action is NORMAL, which forwards all packets to their destination.

As soon as I connect my vSwitch to Opendaylight, the default action is now CONTROLLER but Opendaylight does drop packets that not know the destination

How can I add the default NORMAL action in Opendaylight for any switch that I connect to it? I would like not to drop any packet.

Answer (score 0):

are you installing the l2switch features? I think that might be what is
installing the flow to punt traffic to the controller.

try installing just openflowplugin-flow-services-rest. I think after that
you probably wont have any flows forced on your OVS. At that point you
can manually add any flows you want, via REST api.

This [link](https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/OpenDaylight_OpenFlow_Plugin:End_to_End_Flows) might be helpful for doing that.